# Java Constructor never finish constructing

Tags: java

I am not very good at OOP, i got this problem where the constructor not returning anything.

```
public class CrossEntropy extends Thread{

    protected CEMobileAgentMigrationPlan appOwner;
    private SensorNode[] sensorNodes;
    private JLabel status;
    private JTextArea textArea;
    Integer temp = null;
    boolean first=true;
    int tempor;
    int populasi=1000;
    double a = 0.8;
    double g=(int)(populasi/3);
    int max=appOwner.sensorCount+populasi;
    private double costa=0;
    private int[] samatidak;
    public int[] mem;
    private double[] sortbox;    
    private double w[][]  = new double[max][max];
    private double p[][]  = new double[max][max];
    private double[][] pn;
    private int[][] jalur;
    private double[] cost;
    boolean first2;

    public CrossEntropy(CEMobileAgentMigrationPlan appOwner){
        System.out.println("hi !");
        this.appOwner=appOwner;
        System.out.println("hi hi hello !");
        this.sensorNodes=appOwner.sensorNodeList;
        System.out.println("hello !");
    }

    //method shortened

    public void run(){//engga kepanggil
        System.out.println("Testtament");
        double time = System.currentTimeMillis();
        double thisCost = 0.0;
        double oldCost = 0.0;
        int countSame=0;
        int duration=0;
        double hasilakhir =0;
        boolean cek = false;
        //matrikRate();
        while (countSame<1000){
            membangkitkanTour();
            getCost();
            thisCost = costa;
            if (cek==false){
               oldCost=thisCost;
               cek=true;
            }
            if (thisCost<oldCost){
                 oldCost=thisCost;
                 costa=0;
                 getCost();
                 hasilakhir=costa;
                 countSame=0;

            }else{
                 countSame++;
                 //appOwner.paint();
            }
            costa=0;
        }
        duration = (int) (System.currentTimeMillis()-time);
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        for (int i=0; i< appOwner.sensorCount; i++){
            sb.append("Node Address: " + appOwner.sensorNodeList[mem[i]].getAddress());
            sb.append(" RSSI: " + appOwner.sensorNodeList[mem[i]].getSignalStrength());
            sb.append(" Battery Level: " + appOwner.sensorNodeList[mem[i]].getRemainingBattery());
            sb.append("\n");
        }

       String status = "CE finds Solution after " + duration + " ms with max rating= " + hasilakhir;
       String migrationInfo = sb.toString();
       appOwner.setStatus(status, "Urutan Rute Migrasi: \n" + migrationInfo);

    }

}
```

this is the class where i want to call the constructor

```
public class CEMobileAgentMigrationPlan extends JFrame {
    //protected SensorNodePlacementMap map = null;
    SensorNode[] sensorNodeList;
    CrossEntropy worker;
    private JTextArea textArea;
    boolean started = false;
    private JLabel status;
    int sensorCount;

    public CEMobileAgentMigrationPlan(){
        getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        status = new JLabel("Starting App...");
        textArea = new JTextArea("Listening... \b");
        getContentPane().add(status,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        getContentPane().add(textArea,BorderLayout.CENTER);
        setSize(500,400);
        setTitle("Cross Entropy for Mobile Agent Itinerary Planning");
        this.setResizable(true);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public void setSensorNodes(SensorNode[] sensorNodes){
        this.sensorNodeList = sensorNodes;
        this.sensorCount = this.sensorNodeList.length;
    }

    public int getSensorCount(){
        return sensorCount;
    }

    public SensorNode[] getSensorNodeList(){
        return sensorNodeList;
    }

    public void setStatus(String statusTxt, String migrationInfo){
        status.setText(statusTxt);
        textArea.setText(migrationInfo);
    }

    public void setSensorNodeList(SensorNode[] sensorNodeList) {
        this.sensorNodeList = sensorNodeList;
    }

    public void start(){ // yang ini tidak bisa
        this.started=true;
        //map.update(map.getGraphics());
        //if (worker!= null)worker=null;
        System.out.println("lol");
        worker = new CrossEntropy(this); <<<<< this is the troublemaker
        System.out.println("lol1111");
        worker.setPriority(Thread.MIN_PRIORITY);
        //map.update(map.getGraphics());
        worker.start();
    }


}
```

I already make some similar class to find out what cause it, but i couldn't find any :(

Comment: please explain clearly what the trouble you are having.

Comment: i want to call worker.start();, but i can't. it's because 
worker = new CrossEntropy(this);
never finish constructing

Comment: I imagine that an exception is being thrown.  Did you use a debugger to step through and see where it gets to?

Comment: from method void start();
the output only from System.out.println("lol");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the code sample you provided is complete, then you'll get a NullPointerException when trying to construct the object. The line

```
int max=appOwner.sensorCount+populasi;
```

will cause it, because appOwner is null when the object is constructed. The properties are initialized before the constructor is called. You should calculate that value in the construtor itself, e.g.

```
int max;

public CrossEntropy(CEMobileAgentMigrationPlan appOwner){
    System.out.println("hi !");
    this.appOwner=appOwner;
    max=appOwner.sensorCount+populasi;
    System.out.println("hi hi hello !");
    this.sensorNodes=appOwner.sensorNodeList;
    System.out.println("hello !");
}
```

Comment: OMG, thank you so much, so that's what cause it :)
thanks